# Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: java, swing, awt

The following code appears to produce inconsistent behavior when I run it. On some runs, the canvas ends up appearing grey, but on others it end up colored blue instead. Why is this, and how can I correct it?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class psw extends JFrame {
    String symbols="~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ = + : ; < , > . ? / | \\ '";

    public static void main(String[] args){
    psw app=new psw();
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
    app.setSize(600, 450);
    app.setVisible(true);
    app.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(30,144,255));

    @Override    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 60, 50);
        g.drawLine(60, 50, 220, 20);
        g.drawString(symbols, 10, 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's different about it? Looks the same to me.

Comment: It always looks the same to me...

Comment: @Christian The whole thing is the `psw` class.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the differences?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sorry for that. And yes, it looks the same for me too.

Comment: Can you try adding a call to `super.paint(g);` as the first line in your `paint` method? Also, which JRE are you using... I've tested your code on Windows and Linux, and it works...

Comment: What do you mean with "different view"? Does it _look_ different, or do you mean that it starts a _new instance_ of the frame, instead of e.g. raising an already running instance?

Comment: it may starts with blue or grey background

Comment: try to start it several times one after another and you will see

Comment: it may also start without a string written

Comment: Try changing your code to access the JFrame through the event dispatch thread using invokeLater.

Comment: @user3169729 Try passing the GUI construction code (body of `main()`) to `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`

Comment: i suppose its better to use awt components instead of swing one

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/84681-why-different-view-application.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember to call `super.paint(g);`. That shows the painting.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 60, 50);
    g.drawLine(60, 50, 220, 20);
    g.drawString(symbols, 10, 150);
}
```

- Also, it's not a good idea to paint on top level containers like `JFrame` as they're not double buffered. Instead paint on a component, mostly `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method. Just like with `paint`, you need to call `super.paintComponent`. `super.paintComponent(g)` invokes the `paintComponent` method from the superclass of `JPanel` (the `JComponent` class) to erase whatever is currently drawn on the panel.

---

Here's how it would run using a `JPanel` instead of a `JFrame`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class psw extends JPanel {
    String symbols = "~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ = + : ; < , > . ? / | \\ '";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame app = new JFrame();
                app.add(new psw());
                app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                app.pack();
                app.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(30, 144, 255));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 60, 50);
        g.drawLine(60, 50, 220, 20);
        g.drawString(symbols, 10, 150);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600, 450);
    }
}
```

Comment: this code preserve one background bit sometimes string disappear(

Comment: Se the background _before_ you `setVisible(true)`

Comment: still sometimes disappear a string

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to [access the JFrame through the event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }
});
```

The [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) says:

> Swing event handling code runs on a special thread known as the event
>   dispatch thread. Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on
>   this thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are
>   not "thread safe": invoking them from multiple threads risks thread
>   interference or memory consistency errors. Some Swing component
>   methods are labelled "thread safe" in the API specification; these can
>   be safely invoked from any thread. All other Swing component methods
>   must be invoked from the event dispatch thread. Programs that ignore
>   this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to
>   unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce.

which sounds like what you're seeing.